# Linear Transformation of a Gumbel Random Variable

Tags: linear-transformations

I would like to know what distribution a random variable follows if it is a linear transformation of a Gumbel random variable.

Suppose $X$ follows $Gumbel(0,\beta)$ and $Y=\frac{1}{3}X$.

I would like to know what distribution Y follows. I tried to figure it out with the density functions of the Gumbel distribution, but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula derivation is easy. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar).

> Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to be a monotonic function, then the resulting density function is
>
> $$
> f_Y(y)=f_X\left(g^{-1}(y)\right)\left|\frac{d}{d y}\left(g^{-1}(y)\right)\right|
> $$
>
> here $g^{-1}$ denotes the inverse function.

---

You can use Mathematica to verify your result.

```
(*Define X as Gumbel with parameters \[Alpha] and \[Beta]*)
X \[Distributed] GumbelDistribution[\[Alpha], \[Beta]]

(*Define the transformation*)
Y = 1/3 *X;

(*Get the PDF of Y*)
pdfY = 
 PDF[TransformedDistribution[Y, 
   Distributed[X, GumbelDistribution[\[Alpha], \[Beta]]]], y]
pdfX = PDF[GumbelDistribution[\[Alpha], \[Beta]], x]


PDF[GumbelDistribution[\[Alpha]/3, \[Beta]/3], y] - pdfY // FullSimplify   (* 0 *)
```

$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{3 e^{\frac{3 \left(y-\frac{\alpha }{3}\right)}{\beta }-e^{\frac{3 \left(y-\frac{\alpha }{3}\right)}{\beta }}}}{\beta }
\\
f_X(x)=\frac{e^{\frac{x-\alpha }{\beta }-e^{\frac{x-\alpha }{\beta }}}}{\beta }
$$

transformed r.v. $Y$ distributes $\operatorname{GumbelDistribution}[\alpha/3, \beta/3]$